# Example closed sets for which $\inf(A+B) > \inf A+\inf B$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

A known inequality states:

$$\inf(A+B) ≥ \inf A+\inf B$$

Now what are example (closed) sets of the "$>$" case?

Comment: Why do you think there should be examples? I thought that should be an equality: $\inf(A+B)=\inf A+\inf B$ for any sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R.$ You mean that's not true?

Comment: In the setting of real analysis (as you've tagged this question), $A$ and $B$ are functions, not closed sets.

Comment: @EricTowers Isn't the image of a function conceivable as set?

Comment: A function is not just its image.

Answer (score 1):

In that inequality $A$ and $B$ represent functions, defined on some domain (your question requests some closed interval).

Let $A(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$ and  $B(x) = \cos(2\pi x)$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$.  Then
$$\inf(A) = \inf(B) = -1 \\
\inf(A) + \inf(B) = -2 \\
\inf(A+B) = -\sqrt{2} > \inf(A) + \inf(B) 
$$

Comment: Could you clarify where the $-\sqrt{2}$ comes from?

Comment: $ \inf  (\cos y +\sin y)=\inf (\sqrt 2)(\sin \pi/4 \cos y+\cos \pi/4 \sin y)=\inf \sqrt 2 \sin (y+\pi/4)=-\sqrt 2$. Similarly the max and min of $a\cos y + b\sin y$ are $\pm \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ f, g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ be given by $f(x) = x $ and $g(x) = -x$. We have that $sup \hspace{1mm} f = 1, sup \hspace{1mm}g = 0, sup\hspace{1mm}(f+g) = 0$, so $sup \hspace{1mm}f + sup\hspace{1mm} g = 1 > sup\hspace{1mm}(f+g) = 0$. Furthermore, we have $inf\hspace{1mm} f = 0, inf\hspace{1mm} g = -1, inf\hspace{1mm}(f+g) = 0$, and so $$inf \hspace{1mm}f + inf\hspace{1mm} g = -1<inf\hspace{1mm}(f+g) = 0$$

Comment: $inf(f+g)=-1$ since $f(x)\in [0,1]$ and $g(x) \in [-1,0]$. Then $inf(f+g)=inf([0,1]+[-1,0])=-1$.

Comment: That way you are changing the domain of the function f, that I defined as being [0,1]. You are giving an example where the equality holds.

Comment: The inequality is for any limited sets A, B that are contained on the set of real numbers. I don't necessarily have to pick A different than B.

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: Let A be the set in which we have f(x), for all x belonging to a certain set M, B the set in which we have g(y), for all y belonging to M, and C the set in which we have f(x)+g(x) for all x belonging to M. Clearly, C is contained in A+B, since we need only take x=y, so inf(A+B) is lesser than or equal to inf(f+g). Since inf(A)+ inf(B) = inf f + inf g (same sets) and the infimum of A+B is lesser than or equal to the sum of the infimum of each A and B, by transitivity we conclude that the sum of the infimum of each function is lesser than or equal to the infimum of their sum.

Comment: Note that g(x) does not belong to [-1,0]. -g(x) does.